# Wordpress: unable to get the user logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

The header.php in my project includes at the very beginning a php file with content like this:

```
global $profile;
global $user;

if(is_user_logged_in()){
global $current_user;   
get_currentuserinfo();
$user = array();
$user['username'] = $current_user->user_login;
$user['email'] = $current_user->user_email;
.
.
}
```

On my page template file I am trying to get info from this user object, through the following code

```
$.ajax({ url: path + '/gmail/user.php',
         type: 'post',
         success: function(status) {alert(status);} }
    });
```

which is calling

```
<?php
print_r($user);
?>
```

and I get an empty alert. I get this whether I log in or not. Why could this happen? Is there another solution to picking up the logged in user? maybe with sql?

on using the following code in the php file:

```
global $current_user;  
get_currentuserinfo();
print_r($current_user);
```

I get call to undefined function error

Answer (score 0):

Try put your code calling

```
global $current_user;  
get_currentuserinfo();
```

After wp_head() call in the header.